# How to get date and time till second?

Tags: c#

I have two times as follows :

```
DateTime time1=Datetimepicker1.value;
DateTime time2=file1.creationtime;
```

time1 and time2 both has date and time is showing 12-31-2014 15:00:33
but when i am compairing both the times it is giving false result as :

```
int result=DateTime.Compare(time1,time2);
```

result value is 0.
How?

Comment: Are you sure they are **not** equal? If they are the same, it is normal to get `0` when you compare them. Your title and your question says different things.

Comment: yes actually timeticks are different

Comment: what are you expecting as the result - as @SonerGönül told it is normal to get 0 when they are equal

Answer (score 6):

The result is correct. According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) the function works according to the logic below assuming the dates are named `t1` and `t2`:

```
 __Value Type__      __Condition__ 

 Less than zero      t1 is earlier than t2. 
 Zero                t1 is the same as t2. 
 Greater than zero   t1 is later than t2.
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code is:

```
  int result = DateTime.Compare(t1,t2)
```

Then the following apply:

```
result = 0 => t1=t2
result < 0 => t1<t2
result > 0 => t1>t2
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Compare Method returns Zero for same values. See the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for more details.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

```
DateTime time1 = Datetimepicker1.value;
DateTime time2 = file1.creationtime;
TimeSpan delta = time1 - time2;
bool areSame = Math.Abs(delta.TotalSeconds) < 1;
```